# Affecting KineticJs.Image by css

Tags: css, kineticjs

Hello i'm working on a project that requires canvas manipulation. I need to draw an image and have to move it within the canvas. Which was not so hard to accomplish.. However i need to change my cursor into "move" when hovering the image like

```
img{
    cursor:move;
}
```

I couldn't find any way to do this. Any suggestion??
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drag an Kinetic.Image, you get dragstart and dragend events.

You can change the cursor type in those event handlers:

```
// starting to drag -- display the move cursor

image1.on('dragstart', function () {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'move';
});

// done dragging -- display the regular cursor

image1.on('dragend', function () {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need an element which you can style on the page but with `display: none`, then put that element onto the canvas like this:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```